# Loop that restarts for rate limit

Tags: r, google-maps, loops, while-loop

I am querying [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) which only accepts a maximum of 100 coordinate pairs per request.  Some of my input linestrings from `routes`, however, contain more than 100 segments.

I've written a sample loop which sends a request to the API but it is limited to lines with under 100 segments with `if (nrow(routes$mat) <= 100) {...}` where `routes$mat` is the matrix of coordinate pairs.

```
for (i in 1:length(routes)) {

  if (nrow(routes$mat) <= 100) {
    mat <- paste(apply(mat, 1, paste, collapse=","), collapse="|")

    a <- "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path="
    b <- mat
    c <- "&interpolate=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY"

    request <- paste(a,b,c, sep="")

    con <- curl(request)
    open(con)
    out <- readLines(con)
    mydf <- fromJSON(out)

    close(con)

output <- cbind(mydf$snappedPoints$location$longitude, mydf$snappedPoints$location$latitude)

}
```

My objective is to send all of the lines to the API - regardless of their length, but this means sending them piecemeal.

How would one adjust this loop to send only 100 at a time **if** `mat` is longer than 100 and then concatenate the results into a single `output` ?

So for example, if `nrow(mat)` = 250, there would be 3 outputs, the first with 100, the second with 100, and the third with 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find doing this kind of loop a bit messy, but sometimes it's needed.

For this answer I'm using my `googleway` package which handles the API call for you. I'm also using the `tram_route` data that comes with it. There are 55 rows, so I'm iterating every 10, but with a larger data set you just increase the `by = 10` value.

```
library(googleway)

set_key("roads_api_key", api = "roads")

n <- nrow(tram_route)
subsets <- c(seq(1, n, by = 10), n)
iters <- length(subsets) - 1

## set up a data.frame to store the results
df_result <- data.frame(latitude = numeric(n), 
                        longitude = numeric(n))

for (i in 1:(length(subsets)-1) ) {

    if (i == iters[length(iters)]) {
        idx <- subsets[i]:subsets[i+1]
    } else {
        idx <- subsets[i]:(subsets[i+1] -1)
    }
    print(idx)
    res <- google_snapToRoads(df_path = tram_route[idx, ], 
              lat = "shape_pt_lat", 
              lon = "shape_pt_lon")

    df_result[idx, ] <- res$snappedPoints$location
}

head(df_result)
#    latitude longitude
# 1 -37.81436  144.9386
# 2 -37.81330  144.9415
# 3 -37.81274  144.9429
# 4 -37.81268  144.9430
# 5 -37.81314  144.9439
# 6 -37.81351  144.9443
```

---

And proof if proof be needed

```
set_key("map_api_key")

df_result$colour <- "blue"

google_map() %>%
    add_markers(tram_route, lat = "shape_pt_lat", lon = "shape_pt_lon") %>%
    add_markers(df_result, colour = "colour")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for creating that package - however even when I follow the directions exactly, I get the following error `Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       https://roads.googleapis.com/v1
                     (right here) ------^`  I have encountered other posts with the same issue.  Could you explain the workaround? Using a smaller dataframe works, but the API seems to accept 100 coordinate pairs according to its documentation.  Why is the apparent limit 25 pairs?

Comment: @the_darkside - I don't see an edit to your question. Also, are you getting that `lexical error` from using my code or yours?

Comment: yours - but I figured out that the rate limit is 25 coordinate pairs, it works if the data frame has 25 or less rows

Comment: @the_darkside The [api docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) say it "takes up to 100 GPS points", so it's not quite clear where the 25 limit is coming from.